# azure iot-hub device twin remove desired properties

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-hub-device-management

Following is my device twin payload, By mistake I have added "someKey" property to it.

```
{
   desired: {
      "state": {
           "processor": "running",
           "light": "on"
       },
       "someKey": "someValue"
   }
}
```

I want to remove permanently "someKey" property form JSON twin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To remove "someKey" from twin JSON

assign the null value to "someKey", then only it get removed from device twin JSON.

```
{
   desired: {
      "state": {
           "processor": "running",
           "light": "on"
       },
       "someKey": null
   }
}
```

So Next time onward you will receive JSON as below

```
{
   desired: {
      "state": {
           "processor": "running",
           "light": "on"
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: as of now, you cannot assign it to null in the azure interface

Answer (score 1):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-device-twins#back-end-operations

**Device operations**

Device operations

> The device app operates on the device twin using the following atomic operations:
>
> **Partially update reported properties.** This operation enables the partial update of the reported properties of the currently connected device. This operation uses the same JSON update format that the solution back end uses for a partial update of desired properties.

And then in Back-End operations

> **Partially update device twin.** This operation enables the solution back end to partially update the tags or desired properties in a device twin. The partial update is expressed as a JSON document that adds or updates any property. Properties set to null are removed. The following example creates a new desired property with value `{"newProperty": "newValue"}`, overwrites the existing value of `existingProperty` with `"otherNewValue"`, and removes `otherOldProperty`. No other changes are made to existing desired properties or tags:

`{
    "properties": {
        "desired": {
            "newProperty": {
                "nestedProperty": "newValue"
            },
            "existingProperty": "otherNewValue",
            "otherOldProperty": null
        }
    }
}`

(...)